# Difference between .o and .ko file

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am writing simple Linux module mod.c. 
When I compile mod.c file, it creates two output file **mod.o** and **mod.ko**.
So I just want to know,
What is the difference between mod.o and mod.ko file?

Comment: I think .ko are 2.6 kernel object files whereas .o are 2.4. Read more about it here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO/linuxversions.html

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The short answer is that the **.ko** file is your object file linked with some kernel automatically generated data structures that are needed by the kernel.

The **.o** file is the object file of your module - the result of compiling your C file. The kernel build system then automatically creates another C file with some data structures describing the kernel module (named your_module_kmod.c), compile this C file into another object file and links your object file and the  object file it built together to create the **.ko** file.

The dynamic linker in the kernel that is in charge of loading kernel modules, expects to find the data structure the kernel put in the kmod object in the **.ko** file and will not be able to load your kernel module without them.

Answer (score 22):

> Before Linux 2.6, a user space program would interpret the ELF object
>   (.o) file and do all the work of linking it to the running kernel,
>   generating a finished binary image. The program would pass that image
>   to the kernel and the kernel would do little more than stick it in
>   memory. In Linux 2.6, the kernel does the linking. A user space
>   program passes the contents of the ELF object file directly to the
>   kernel. For this to work, the ELF object image must contain additional
>   information. To identify this particular kind of ELF object file, we
>   name the file with suffix ".ko" ("kernel object") instead of ".o" For
>   example, the serial device driver that in Linux 2.4 lived in the file
>   serial.o in Linux 2.6 lives in the file serial.ko.

from http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO/linuxversions.html .

Answer (score 0):

**.ko** is the extension of a module file and **.o** is the extension of an object file.

An object file is created from compiling source files, with **.c** and **.h** extensions.

A module file is created by linking relevant object files and necessary dependencies.

The module file is a loadable kernel module (**LKM**) that can be dynamically loaded and unloaded to a running kernel without restarting the computer.
The object files serve as the building blocks for creating the module file.

Here is a line from the makefile of the **scsi_mod** module:

drivers/scsi/Makefile:**scsi_mod**-y += scsi.o hosts.o scsi_ioctl.o

The above line has been taken from the Makefile that is located under **drivers/scsi** location.

**scsi_mod** is the module file that is created by linking the following object files: scsi.o, hosts.o and scsi_ioctl.o