# How do I cross compile a single module?

Tags: arm, linux-device-driver, cross-compiling

What I need to cross compile is the USB gadget serial driver (g_serial.ko). I have my toolchain installed and checked out the sources from kernel.org.
Now what to do to just compile that single module?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You know you need to compile kernel once anyway right?

Comment: Yeah, I figured I need  to run make oldconfig once. But there's a lot of settings and I'm not quite sure about some of them.

Comment: Actually it's the first time Im compiling the kernel. Do I need to run a patch for arm on the kernel because when I run make oldconfig, I can't choose any ARM processors in the "processor family" menu.

Comment: Every device is different, so you need to find some pointers for configuration of your device. A previous built, some web page for the same device. To repeat again, ARM devices are not generic and Linux kernel doesn't have stable API for modules (http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/stable_api_nonsense.html)

Comment: As per [federico](http://stackoverflow.com/users/423795/federico), you need to set **CROSS_COMPILE** and `ARCH=arm` when running `make oldconfig`.  If you don't the `make` / the **kbuild** system will default to a *x86-linux-pc* when run from such an environment.

Answer (score 1):

From the kernel source directory

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/your/cross/compile/prefix M=path/to/module/directory
```

or

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/your/cross/compile/prefix path/to/module/directory
```

Comment: +1 [How ko is built](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511672/how-ko-file-is-built), and others; they are all slight variations of the same principals.